# updateChildren overwriting existing data on Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on setting values in multiple paths with the function, updateChildren().

When my hash maps have all the required entries, 5 items, the writes to the database happen with no problem.

But if I needed to only update the values in my hash map (pictured with 4 items), every value that does not exist on my hash map gets erased on my database. (my value for imageURL gets erased on the database since the value doesn't exist in my hashmap).

From the documentation, it seems to me that only if the value to a key is null, the value at the specific node will be removed. With what I'm doing, when a value is null on my device, I'm excluding it from being included in my hash map.

Am I doing something wrong with updating my children values?

[All populated values writing to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kPcU.png)
[Selectively populated values, sans imageURL, which writes to the database but erases the already existing value for 'imageURL'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx2TG.png)

Comment: Please share us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the key and old value. Alternatively rewrite your update function to set values one by one in a loop on Hasmap. Note that when you write a hashmap using put value on a database reference  then the original contents are deleted and new contents are inserted at that location. In other words `putValue` on a database reference deletes all the children of the reference then it writes children available in the hasmap supplied. Consider the following example:

```
map.add ("id", 1);
map.add ("msg", "hello");
dbRef.putValue (map);
map.clear ();
map.add ("msg", "world");
dbRef.putValue (map);
```

Now `dbRef` node looks like

```
dbRef:
           msg : world
```

`id` is no more there.

**EDIT**

Since this is the accepted answer so I am adding some references to find the same officially. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)

> For basic write operations, you can use *setValue()* to save data to a specified reference, **replacing any existing data** at that path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Virendra! That's unfortunate that the hashmaps replace existing values, this isn't the way iOS Firebase works so I was caught off guard. I'll have to work it out as you have suggested. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The Firebase documentation is also misleading... As stated on the docs, 'To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the updateChildren() method.' Yet when you use the updateChildren() method with their shown example of a hash map, you overwrite over your child nodes.